# How to change the root certificate of a generated KeyPair on an android device?

Tags: android, kotlin, certificate, keystore, key-pair

I want to generate a KeyPair on my Android device that have a root certificate as a *Google Hardware Attestation Root certificate*.

I've seen in the documentation on Android [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec) that I can change the self-signed certificate

> For asymmetric key pairs, a self-signed X.509 certificate will be also generated and stored in the Android Keystore. This is because the KeyStore abstraction does not support storing key pairs without a certificate. The subject, serial number, and validity dates of the certificate can be customized in this spec. The self-signed certificate may be replaced at a later time by a certificate signed by a Certificate Authority (CA).

I can see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation#root_certificate) that I can get chain of X.509 certificates associated with the hardware-backed keystore with the the keyStore `getCertificateChain()`

> Use a KeyStore object's `getCertificateChain()` method to get a reference to the chain of X.509 certificates associated with the hardware-backed keystore.

However, I haven't found how I can change the certificate on my KeyPair with the *Google Hardware Attestation Root certificate*

```
private fun generateKeyPairAttestationAndGetPublicKey(): String {
     val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
     val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
         KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore"
     )

     keyPairGenerator.initialize(
         KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
             "my-mobile-key",
             KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT
            )
             .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
             .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
             .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
             .build()
     )
     keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()

     keyStore.load(null)
     val keyEntry = keyStore.getEntry("my-mobile-key", null) as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry
     val x509Cert = keyEntry.certificate as? X509Certificate ?: throw Exception("Certificate generated by the KeyPair is not a X509Certificate")
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: You can't change a certificate after it's been generated. The documentation you quoted specifically says **replaced**, so you'll have to generate a new cert and have it signed with the root cert.

Comment: Does that mean that I can't have a KeyPair trusted by Google Hardware Attestation Root certificate ? That seems odd to me that we can't do that on a Google device.